# Append String Split to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, string, dataframe, pandas

I am trying to append some of the words from a string into the Pandas Dataframe but after few trials it seems that I may not be succesful in it.

My code till now :

```
str = "I am an avid user of Pandas"
str_split = str.split()
panda_frame = pandas.DataFrame(columns=["First","Second","Third","Fourth"])
```

Now I just want to add "I","am","an","avid" to the pandas dataframe.

Comment: Why? This seems a random thing to do... (using only the first four items)

Comment: Its merely an example and yes there are many more columns to add and recursively read many lines.

Comment: Whats the input, a text file? How does it look like? etc...

Comment: When posting here you need to show the actual input file and what it looks like, because from your comments, it seems as though my method wont work for that, but my method perfectly answers your question the way you phrased it

Comment: I suppose Ryan that we are not here for downvoting just becuase there are some less words in the question. About "actual input", strange request, the site administartor always ask for replica and not actual.

Comment: @root. yeah its basically a text file

Comment: @LonelySoul 1, I haven't downvoted you. 2 in some cases, actual lines from the input file, or at least lines that look like the correct lines is very useful. I also updated my answer with a bit of guessing based on these comments, hopefully you find that helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a csv you can use pandas `read_csv` like this:

```
import pandas
my_file = 'example.csv'
df = pandas.read_csv(my_file)
```

if you can't do that for some odd reason, you need to merge single dataframes using pandas [concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html):

let us say that `strings` is a list of the strings similar to the example you gave

```
count = 0
dfs = []
for my_str in strings:
    str_split = my_str.split()
    data = dict(zip(cols,str_split))
    panda_frame = pandas.DataFrame(data,index=[count],columns = cols)
    dfs.append(panda_frame)
    count += 1
df = pandas.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: ValueError: If use all scalar values, must pass index.....  Was found after running the last line and also how will you add next sentence to the same frame

Comment: @LonelySoul "the next sentence to the same frame"... huh? Please can you give a better example of what you want. (We're really not mind readers...)

Comment: I edited it 5 minutes ago so that that didn't happen...try again, it will work, it does for me

Comment: @Andy Hayden ... Sure. So there is a text file consisting of more than 200 lines of facebook comments which is in csv. They are sepeartaed by space and comma basically but no pattern. I am trying to build a frame in which the differenet attributes of fb comments will be sent. It's noit json otherwise half of job was finished.

Comment: @LonelySoul explaining that could make for a much better question... Give the first few lines of the csv (or some pretend ones). :)

Comment: why don't you just use `pandas.read_csv`